# Excel: Cannot change the date format of cell in pivot table

Tags: excel, sorting, date, format, pivot-table

I would like to have your help for the below issue.
I cannot change the format in a specific column in a pivot table where I have dates.
The current format is 10-Mar and I would like to change it to 10/3/2020.
Please see the attached screenshots.

Thank you in advance.

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]
[image: screen3]
[image]

Comment: Questions: 1. What format is the date in the underlying data? 2. Are the dates grouped? 3. What version of Excel.

Comment: One can convert date 10/3/2020 (in cell A2) to text "10-Mar" with TEXT Function =TEXT(A2,"D-MMM")

You underlying data may be text and therefore "Number Format" menu is not available in the "Field Settings"